# IIF Parameter Embedded inside SSRS SQL Query

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, iif

I hope you could help me understand the following phrase.  They are part of an SQL query in my SSRS report.  From Report Builder -> Report -> a Dataset, I selected Dataset Properties -> Query

The section below is part of the `WHERE` clause: it refers to the SSRS parameters and I could not understand what they meant. They do not look like the simple IIF statement I used to work with, as they contains many signs like "','") & "') " & .
I appreciate very much if you can help explain the meaning by breaking them down.

```
AND PTE_code = '" & Parameters!p_TE.Value & "'") & " 
AND PTY_code IN ('" & Join(Parameters!p_TY.Value,"','") & "') " & Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!pFDate.Value)," "," 
AND (H_expiry_date >= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!pFDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "' OR H_expiry_date IS NULL)" ) & Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!pTDate.Value)," "," 
AND (H_expiry_date <= '" & UCase(Format(Parameters!pTDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")) & "' OR H_expiry_date IS NULL)" ) & iif(Parameters!p_PC.Value="ALL"," "," AND PC = '" & Parameters!p_PC.Value & "' ")
```

Notes:
PTE_code, PTY_code, H_expiry_date, PC are the field names from tables.
p_TE, p_TY, p_FDate, p_TDate, p_PC are parameters from the report.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever there is a double quote in this, the SQL query string is getting composed in Reporting Services. The single quotes are sent to the DB server as part of the query string, delimiting the strings: so this will actually send a query something like:

```
AND PTE_code = 'p_TEValue' 
AND PTY_code IN ('p_TYValue1','p_TYValue2') 
AND (H_expiry_date >= 'pFDateValueFormatted' OR H_expiry_date IS NULL) 
AND (H_expiry_date <= 'pTDateValueFormatted' OR H_expiry_date IS NULL)
AND PC = 'p_PCValue'
```

The `IIF` statements put a single space instead of parts of the where above, when some of the parameters are empty. (The second parameter of the `IIF` is a space, which is returned when the first parameter of the `IIF` evaluates to true. The third (last) parameter of the `IIF` is returned if the first parameter evaluates to false.

This query should be rewritten to avoid the SQL injection vulnerability on the `p_TEValue` parameter, by the way. And I would probably rewrite to avoid the Date string formatting, if `H_expiry_date` is a DATETIME column.

Comment: Thank you so much Jamie for your help.  I need rewrite the condition, because my users would like to have the p_PCValue parameter a multiple choice one.

Comment: I do not understand how to end the entire query, the query started with 
="Select .....  , then ended with   
& iif(Parameters!p_PC.Value="ALL"," ","  AND PC = '" & Parameters!p_PC.Value & "' ")
I need to rewrite that last part of the condition, because my users would like to have the p_PCValue parameter a multiple choice one.  
I re-wrote 
---->  & iif(Parameters!p_PC.Value="ALL"," ","  AND PC = '" & Parameters!p_PC.Value & "' ")   
into  ---->  AND PC  IN ('" & Join(Parameters!p_PC.Value,"','") & "')   
and then I received the dataset error.  Can you help?

Comment: This is different than your original question. You should start a new question for this. (Stack Overflow tries to keep all the answers matching the question that is written.) Also, voting up useful answers and accepting the correct answer are helpful to the community.